# PHP return "Array" instead of Array data

Tags: php, javascript, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php pass array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287654/php-pass-array-to-javascript)
>   [How to pass PHP array parameter to Javascript Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502107/how-to-pass-php-array-parameter-to-javascript-function)

So I'm trying to pull an individual element at random from an array consisting of data pulled from a database. This is a simplified version of the php code.

```
        function getID() {
                $result = array('1','2','3','4');

                $id = $result[array_rand($result)];
                return $id;
        }
```

From here, I'm defining a JavaScript variable using the returned ID.

Here's the weird thing, when I define the JS variable using the passed return $id, the javascript variable is defined as = "Array" instead of the $id data.

IF I change the php code to this:

```
        function getID() {
                $result = array('1','2','3','4');

                $id = array_rand($result);
                return $id;
        }
```

The javascript variable is defined as the $id, which is the array key, not the array data.

So I tried changing the php code to this:

```
        function getID() {
                $result = array('1','2','3','4');

                return $result[0];
        }
```

But the javascript gets defined as "Array" again.

It's as if the php won't take an array marker.

Any ideas here are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried converting the data to JSON with json_encode?

Comment: Show us html that it generates and how you print it out.

Comment: I nom'd this for re-opening because it is nothing close to a duplicate of the above threads.  This is about javascript recognizing a specific piece of data from an array; not an entire array.

Comment: @Jmichelsen I'm unable to reproduce your error with the code provided; could you please post your html, javascript, and the rest of your php?

Comment: @Daedalus I got it working with the answer posted by PLB below. The entire PHP/JS is pretty complex, pulling data from MySQL and running other functions on it, so I wanted to keep things simple thus the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly pass arrays directly from php to javascript. Use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to return your array as Json encoded string.

```
function getID() {
   $result = array('1','2','3','4');

   json_encode($result);
}
```

And in javascript you can do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonFormattedStringThatWasGeneratedByFunctionGetID);
```

Most browsers support [`JSON.parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Edit:** I've misunderstood your question at first but you can still use this method and get desired item on client-side but this is far from perfect solution. I'll leave this answer as another option.

Comment: The user isn't trying to pass an array.  They're trying to pass a single value, as evidenced by their question.

Comment: @Daedalus Thank you very much. I've edited answer hoping it maybe useful for OP.

Comment: @Daedalus That's right, just trying to get a single digit. However, PLB pointed me in the right direction. Did you have a different solution? Either way, appreciate the help.

Comment: @PLB That did the trick, sort of. Using json_encode I was able to get a JSON element consisting of {'title':'id'}. I used JSON.stringify to create a string, and result.split to get the ID I needed. Then I had to strip away the } from the JSON element. But in the end, success! Thanks a ton :)